# Safest rsync command options?

Tags: backup, permission, rsync

What are the safest commands to use with `rsync` to copy from one hard drive, all its content to a new hard drive, both external through my Mac.

**The important thing** is I want to be sure permissions and privileges won't risk denying me access in the future if I try to access files on a different computer with a different user account for ex.

Is `rsync -a` the answer ? Because I read it conserves permissions and privileges :/.

Thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`rsync -a` preserves permissions as far as your current computer/account is concerned. Accessing files from a different user/different account is controlled by a lot of parameters outside of `rsync`'s influence (mainly by the access protocoll and its options used when mounting the drive).

Comment: Thanks for your input ! So if I backup with "rsync -a" from one external drive to another by connecting them both to my Mac, then the files will be readable, writable and executable on other computers than this Mac when using the destination external drive ?

Comment: @MFJC Most probably yes :-)